# Accessing low-level registers of an embedded device using Python

Tags: python, c, embedded

I have an embedded device with Python installed on in. Is it possible to explicitly access registers in pure Python, or should I write C extensions for my Python code?

Comment: Have you also got any operating system there?

Comment: @thg435: No. But I would be also interested in the case that I had an operating system.

Comment: I'm just curious is this something like http://code.google.com/p/python-on-a-chip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you can't access the low level registers. I recommend just writing a short C extension code to allow Python to access the registers you need.

Answer (score 1):

I assume "registers" means "i/o-mapped device registers".

If you have Linux-x86, there is a Python [PortIO](http://portio.inrim.it/) package.

From the link: "PortIO is a Python wrapper for the port I/O macros like outb, inb, etc. provided by the C library on Linux x86 platforms. "